# Variavel que muda de acordo com o botão apertado

Tags: java, android

Tenho dois métodos diferentes em dois botões diferentes. o Método `onE` que soma `3` a variável e o Método `onM` que tira `-1` da variável. O problema é que quando coloco essa variável para aparecer no `textoid.setText(variavel)` o *app* trava. Eu teria que converter esse "int" variável para `String`, ou estou errando na estrutura do código? Segue ele:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button botaomid;
private Button botaoeid;
private TextView textoid;
public int variavel;


public void onM () {

    variavel = variavel - 1;
}

public void onE () {

    variavel = variavel + 3;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botaoeid =(Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoeid);
    botaomid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaomid);
    textoid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoid);


    textoid.setText(variavel);

    botaomid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onM();
        }
    });


    botaoeid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        onE();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem que inicializar sua variável, definindo um valor para ela. Ex.: `0`.

```
public int variavel = 0;
```

Para não ocorrer o erro, basta inserir `""` antes da variável. Veja abaixo:

```
textoid.setText(""+variavel);
```

ou

```
textoid.setText(String.valueOf(variavel));
```

Fazendo `setText(int)` você está se referindo a um recurso a partir do arquivo XML, não o valor em si.

E por ultimo, para que seu `TextView` seja alterado no momento em que clicar no botão, você tem que fazer o `setText` dentro de cada botão, desta forma:

```
botaomid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onM();
            textoid.setText(""+variavel);

        }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou cara, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @JuniorKlawa Por nada bro! Tamo ae!